# Equivalent sorting with LINQ orderby keyword vs. OrderBy extension method

Tags: c#, sorting, linq-to-objects, .net-3.5

I'm trying to come up with a set of chained `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` extension method calls that is equivalent to a LINQ statement using the `orderby` keyword.

My LINQ statement using the `orderby` keyword looks like this:

```
List<Summary> sortedSummaries = new List<Summary>(
    from summary in unsortedSummaries
    orderby summary.FieldA ascending,
            summary.FieldB ascending,
            summary.FieldC ascending,
            summary.FieldD ascending
    select summary);
```

Now, I would guess that an equivalent version, using chained `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` extension method calls would look like this:

```
List<Summary> sortedSummaries = new List<Summary>(unsortedSummaries);    
sortedSummaries.OrderBy(x => x.FieldA).ThenBy(x => x.FieldB).ThenBy(x => x.FieldC).ThenBy(x => x.FieldD);
```

However, this gives me quite different results than using my LINQ statement using the `orderby` keyword.

What might I be doing wrong here?

---

The reason I'm trying to convert to using chained `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` extension method calls is that I need to use a custom comparer on `FieldD`, like so:

```
.ThenBy(x => x.FieldD, new NaturalSortComparer())
```

I can't figure how to do that using LINQ statements with the `orderby` keyword, so I thought using extension methods might get me farther, but since I'm not able to get my extension method version to give me the same results as my `orderby` keyword version, I'm back to the drawing board, for the moment.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dot notation call isn't assigning the result to anything. It ought to be:

```
var sortedSummaries = unsortedSummaries.OrderBy(x => x.FieldA)
                                       .ThenBy(x => x.FieldB)
                                       .ThenBy(x => x.FieldC)
                                       .ThenBy(x => x.FieldD);
```

Don't forget that LINQ operators never change the *existing* sequence - they return a *new* sequence with the appropriate differences (in this case, ordering). If you want to sort in-place, use `List<T>.Sort`.

The query above is exactly what the LINQ part of your original code does. However, if I wanted to construct a list from it, I wouldn't pass it to the `List<T>` constructor - I'd use the `ToList` extension method:

```
var sortedSummaries = unsortedSummaries.OrderBy(x => x.FieldA)
                                       .ThenBy(x => x.FieldB)
                                       .ThenBy(x => x.FieldC)
                                       .ThenBy(x => x.FieldD)
                                       .ToList();
```

Check that that does what you expect it to (it really should) - and then you can put your custom comparison in.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that was it. Makes perfect sense now. I thought I was accounting for LINQ operators never changing the existing sequence, but I must have gotten mixed up :)